# Variable is not shown in Flask template

Tags: python, django-templates, flask, jinja2, templating

I'm very new with templating engines and need help from someone smarter. Trying to generate searching results with Flask template, encountered lot of pain. Flask :

```
@app.route('/*?search', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.args.get('q'):

            qList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  request.args.get('q') ).split()

            htmlA = """
                    <div class="results" > 
                    <p>

                    """
            htmlB = """
                    </p>
                    <br></br>
                    </div>
                    """
            found = None
            for it in qList :
                found = htmlA + RESULT_BLAH_BLAH_METHOD( it ) + htmlB

            return render_template( 'list_of_found_items.html', found=found )
```

and html template part:

```
<somewhere in html>
    {% block content %}
        {{ found }}
    {% endblock %}
</somewhere in html>
```

With this, results are not shown on page even if are existing and checked with print to console output. What I've missed? Thank you.

Comment: what is `L`? is it empty?

Comment: what is `rez` supposed to be?

Comment: Thank you. I've just edited, but it didn't show up.

Comment: `render_template('...', found)` => `render_template('...', found=found)` Otherwise the template does not know what `found` is.

Comment: Got results on screen but as raw text, and browser see it like: 
                    &lt;div class=&#34;col2&#34; &gt; 
                    &lt;h2&gt;
                    
                    fileSystem_GrafickeKartice.txt
                    &lt;hr&gt;&lt;/hr&gt;&lt;/h2&gt;
                    &lt;/div&gt;

Comment: this is because of autoescaping. flask considers your formatting (the for loop around qList values) should be in the template. Pass qList directly to your template and do the formatting there.

Comment: Yes, I would do it in JS simply, but dunno where the Flask renderer keeps template to edit it. It has no sense to write it to disk and reread.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. This kind of formatting is what templates are made for. The rendered template is not written to disk, if that is your worry. It is built and sent to the client on the fly.

Comment: But in that case it would be easier for me to code few python methods to generate html, instead of using rendering engine which don't give me DOM acces!?

Comment: I still don't understand where you are getting at. your python formatting can be replaced by about the same number of templating lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autoescaping prevent from directly writing HTML in python. Your code could be re-written as:

```
qList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  request.args.get('q') ).split()
return render_template('list_of_found_items.html', items = map(RESULT_BLAH_BLAH_METHOD, qList))
```

And the following template

```
<somewhere in html>
    {% block content %}
        {% for item in qList %}
            <div class="results" >
                <p>{{item}}</p>
                <br></br>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</somewhere in html>
```

Comment: For some reason TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - at "map()" function. Trying to find cause..

Comment: I made a simple list and it works without "map()". I can implement my function in some other way. Consider it "solved", thank you for your time.